# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't hit breakpoint when attach to local IIS ASP.Net Core process

Tags: iis, postman, microservices, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have deployed a few ASP.Net Core app (only microservices) each on a different Local ISS Site with differente TCP ports (eg. http://localhost:650X).
Now I want to debug such services with VS17 but currently I cannot hit any breakpoint.
If a test a service (eg. Postman) it gives me a 200OK response but VS is still giving me "No symbols have been loaded...". I built the solution with 'Debug' configuration, anyCPU and published method 'Debug', 'FileSystem', .Net 47. How can I solve this issue ?
I had a look at the publishing directory and I can see .pdb files.
Let me now if more information are needed.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which process did you attach to? Also show your web.config.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version vs2017 you have used now? Which version asp.net core you have used now?  How you attench the right process? Besides, I suggest you could also follow below [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2019) to republish the application and try again.